# How to cut and assign the string to a dynamic array inside the for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is what i have done to perform this function but I am not getting what i want.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9 

for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ )) 
do 
x=`echo $DIRECTIONPART1| awk -F'-' '{print $i}'` 
myarray[$i]=$x 

done

for (( c=1; c<=3; c++ )) 
do 
echo ${myarray[$c]} 
done
```

Problem we realised at this step

```
x=`echo $DIRECTIONPART1| awk -F'-' '{print $i}'`
```

Please help me in getting the result

This is what i get :

```
4-7-9 
4-7-9
4-7-9
```

But I want this:
4
7
9

Comment: Your hashtag needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, as you are using non-POSIX features (arrays and a C-style for loop).

Answer (score 0):

you are right with line of problem. The problem is that you cant use `$i` as variable in `print`. I have tried little workaround which worked for me:

```
x=`echo $DIRECTIONPART1| awk -F '-' -v var=$i '{print $var }'`
```

in all it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9

for (( i=1; i<=3; i++ ))
do
x=`echo $DIRECTIONPART1| awk -F '-' -v var=$i '{print $var }'`
myarray[$i]=$x
done

for (( c=1; c<=3; c++ ))
do
echo ${myarray[$c]}
done
```

with expected output:

```
# sh test.sh
4
7
9
#
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest portable way to get the desired output is to use `$IFS` (in a subshell):

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9
(IFS=- && echo $DIRECTIONPART1)
```

The shell array would not work portably, as POSIX, ksh, and bash do not
agree on arrays.  POSIX doesn't have any; ksh and bash use different syntax.

---

If you really want an array, I would suggest to do the entire thing in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9

awk -v v=${DIRECTIONPART1} 'BEGIN {
  n=split(v,a,"-")
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    print a[i]
  }
}'
```

This will produce one line for each value in the string:

```
4
7
9
```

---

And if you want [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arrays, drop the `#!/bin/sh`, and do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9
A=( $(IFS=- && echo $DIRECTIONPART1) )

for ((i=0;i<=${#A[@]};i++))
do
  echo ${A[i]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `awk` multiple times, or even once, is not the right thing to do. Use the `bash` built-in `read` to populate the array.

```
# Note that the quotes here are only necessary to
# work around a bug that was fixed in bash 4.3. It
# doesn't hurt to use them in any version, though.
$ IFS=- read -a myarray <<< "$DIRECTIONPART_1"
$ printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"
4
7
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9

# Create array
IFS='-' read -a array <<< "$DIRECTIONPART1"

#To access an individual element:
echo "${array[0]}"

#To iterate over the elements:
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done

#To get both the index and the value:
for index in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$index ${array[index]}"
done
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash test.sh
4
4
7
9
0 4
1 7
2 9
```

**OR**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIRECTIONPART1=4-7-9

array=(${DIRECTIONPART1//-/ })
for index in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$index ${array[index]}"
done
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash test1.sh
0 4
1 7
2 9
```